# the pseudometric induced by a measure

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space.

We can define a pseudometric $d$ on $\Sigma$ in the following way:

$$d(A, B) = \mu(A\bigtriangleup{}B)$$

where $A\bigtriangleup{}B = (A\cup{}B)\setminus{}(A\cap{}B)$ is the symmetric difference.

Does this metric have a name? What does the topology induced by $d$ on $\Sigma$ tell us about the measure?

Comment: It's just the standard (pseudo)metric induced by the measure; normally this is defined on the quotient measure algebra (modding out the null sets), making it a metric on that. It's used to define a separable measure: iff this metric space is separable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming $\mu(X)<\infty$, this is the restriction of the $L^1$ metric on $L^1(X)$ to the subspace consisting of characteristic (a.k.a. indicator) functions.  Clearly this is a closed (topological) subspace, and therefore $\Sigma$ is a complete metric space under this metric.

As far as I know, this metric itself doesn't have a name.  In some sense, it should give precisely the same information about the measure that you can get from the space of $L^1$ functions.

**Edit:** As Theo pointed out, the last sentence isn't quite correct, since the subspace of characteristic functions cannot actually be recognized from within $L^1$.  For example, $L^1([0,1])$ and $L^1([0,2])$ are isomorphically isometric via the map $f(x) \mapsto f(x/2)/2$, but the corresponding $\Sigma$'s are not isometric. In general, the total measure $\mu(X)$ of the underlying space cannot necessarily be recovered from $L^1(X)$, but $\mu(X)$ is the diameter of $\Sigma$ as a metric space.

**Edit #2:**  Some further comments:

1. Note that $\Sigma$ is a topological group under $\bigtriangleup$, and is therefore homogeneous.  As a result, we can assume that we know which point of $\Sigma$ represents the empty set $\emptyset$.
2. Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation
   $$
   A\sim B \qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad \mu(A \bigtriangleup B) = 0.
   $$
   Since $\Sigma$ is homogeneous, every equivalence class under $\sim$ has the same cardinality as the equivalence class of $\emptyset$.  Thus, we can use the pseudometric structure on $\Sigma$ to determine the cardinality of the collection of measure-zero sets.
3. Assuming $\mu(X) < \infty$, the metric structure on $\Sigma$ can also be used to reconstruct the $\sigma$-algebra structure on $\Sigma/\sim$.  In particular, if $A,B\in \Sigma/\sim$, we can tell whether $A\subset B$ (modulo sets of measure zero) by checking whether
   $$
   d(\emptyset,A) + d(A,B) = d(\emptyset,B)\text{,}
   $$
   and this lets us reconstruct the notions of countable union and complement.
4. According to point #3, the metric structure on $\Sigma$ lets us reconstruct $\Sigma/\sim$ as a measure algebra (see [this reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=3mRo0wTdNv0C&lpg=PA3&dq=isomorphism%20of%20measure%20spaces&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q=isomorphism%20of%20measure%20spaces&f=false) for the definitions used in this paragraph).  Moreover, it should be clear that $\Sigma/\sim$ and $\Sigma'/\sim$ are conjugate as measure algebras if and only if they are isometric as metric spaces.

We conclude that, in the case where $\mu(X) < \infty$, the metric structure on $\Sigma$ contains only the following information:

(1) The cardinality of the collection of sets of measure zero and

(2) The conjugacy class of $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ as a measure algebra.

According to [this reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=3mRo0wTdNv0C&lpg=PA3&dq=isomorphism%20of%20measure%20spaces&pg=PA5#v=onepage&q=isomorphism%20of%20measure%20spaces&f=false), any two separable, non-atomic probability spaces are measure algebra conjugate.  Therefore, as long as $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is separable and non-atomic, the only information contained in point (2) is the total measure $\mu(X)$ of $X$.

Comment: Jim: This space has much more information than the metric space $L^1$ alone. Note that $d(\phi,A) = \mu(A)$, so the measure is stored in there. However, for two mutually absolutely continuous measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ the spaces $L^1(\mu)$ and $L^1(\nu)$ are isometrically isomorphic via multiplication by the Radon Nikodym derivatives. Thus your last statement must involve more information on $L^1$ than purely metric information. The metric space $(\Sigma,d)$ has much more structure (it is a Boolean algebra with a topology) that can be exploited differently than $L^1$ as a Banach space alone.

Comment: @Theo: I see, you can't actually recognize the characteristic functions within $L^1$ using the metric, so there's more information contained in $\Sigma$ than there is in $L^1$. I'll edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: Your addition is very nice and shows that in the separable case my point is essentially moot.

Answer (score 5):

The function $d$ is sometimes called the Fréchet-Nikodym metric; for example, see section 1.12(iii) on page 53 of *Measure Theory: Volume 1* by V. Bogachev.

---

**Added:** Google Books led me to the *Encyclopedia of Distances* by Michel M. Deza, Elena Deza. There the metric is called the symmetric difference metric, or the Fréchet-Nikodym-Aronszyan metric, or the measure metric.

Comment: Does Bogachev give references to the works of Fréchet and Nikodym? (Google doesn't let me look)

Comment: @Theo Bogachev lists 16 works of M. Frechet and 10 works of O. Nikodym in the back of his book. However, section 1.12(iii) *Metric Boolean Algebra* doesn't have any references in it. So it's not clear exactly which of these works discuss the metric, or how it got its name.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I feared... So I'll have to dig in the library if I really want to know. I'll post a comment here if I should happen to find something worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

Separability of this spaces gives separability of the $L^p$ spaces, $1\le p < \infty$.