# Pseudo metric defined in term of outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, measure-theory

Let $X$ be our space and $\wp(X)$ its power set. Then $\rho:\wp(X)\times\wp(X)\to [0,\infty]$ defined by $\rho(A,B)=m^{*}(A\Delta B)$ is a pseudo metric on $\wp(X)$ (the possibility $\rho(A,B)=\infty$ does not seem to be a problem).

We might restrict our attention to the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets, say $\mathcal{M}$, and assume $m(X)<\infty$. Then $\rho$ definitely gives a topology on $\mathcal{M}$. Moreover, it is readily seen that if $\mathcal{A}\subset\wp(X)$ generates $\mathcal{M}$, then $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $\mathcal{M}$ in this topology.

It seems to me that such a metric might be interesting but somehow I cannot find any book even mentioning this topology. Thus I wonder whether someone has looked into this.

Any reference would be welcome! Thanks!

Comment: It is mentioned in the textbook of Halmos on measure theory.

Comment: Also it is mentioned in *Measure and Integration Theory* (2001) by Heinz Bauer on page 14.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’ll find some information about the pseudometric and a couple of references in the answers to [this earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44171/the-pseudometric-induced-by-a-measure). The metric induced on the quotient if you mod out the null sets is apparently known as the *symmetric difference* metric, the *Fréchet-Nikodym-Aronszyan* (or simply *Fréchet-Nikodym*) metric, or the *measure* metric.

One way in which it is used can be seen in [this post](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/03/254a-notes-0a-an-alternate-approach-to-the-caratheodory-extension-theorem/) to Terry Tao’s blog.

A generalization of this pseudometric is treated in [*Extension of measures and integrals by the help of a pseudometric*](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/128608) by Beloslav Riečan (Mathematica Slovaca, Vol. 27 (1977), No. 2, 143-152); it looks interesting at first glance, but I’ve not actually read the paper.

Comment: @Hui Yu: You can find some applications of (and references to) this metric in my answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\rho (A,B) = \int_X | \chi_A - \chi_B | dm$, so $\rho$ is just the $L^1$ metric restricted to the subset of indicator functions. So you can already deduce some properties of this metric space by using what you already know about $L^1$.